# Can we make google chrome act as a kiosk browser with only one website access?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, kiosk

I am a fresh IT graduate and in my new job, I have to setup a kiosk system, with a normal PC but that needs to display only the HR website to employees for viewing vacation hours and requesting vacation. We do not want them to access any other website on the browser. Mostly we use google chrome, so I was wondering if we can configure it in a way, that it only allows the HR website to go open and nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running latest Chrome for Windows in kiosk mode](https://superuser.com/questions/716426/running-latest-chrome-for-windows-in-kiosk-mode)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming it is windows based, you can configure the firewall to block all other traffic.  You will have to find and allow the DNS server also.  You may also need to allow access to microsoft and the google update server so chrome and windows can update themselves.

Depending on how your network is setup, your local networking team could also put a block in place at a higher level.  Then even booting off a USB stick won't get you addition websites.

First identify what you need to communicate with which is your **dns server,dhcp server, gateway**, and your 1 website. ipconfig /all should give you most of it.  **If you don't allow the additional IPs you won't access any websites.**

**You may not block 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.255 if you use DHCP**

```
now create ranges. say you need 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,100.1.1.1
range 1:  0.0.0.1-1.1.1.0
range 2:  1.1.1.2-2.2.2.1
range 3:  2.2.2.2-100.1.1.0
range 4:  100.1.1.2-255.255.255.254
```

then combine them as shown below

from an administrative command prompt:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="block all!" protocol=any dir=out remoteport=any remoteip=0.0.0.1-1.1.1.0,1.1.1.2-2.2.2.1,2.2.2.2-100.1.1.0,100.1.1.2-255.255.255.254 action=block
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your kiosk is running Windows, you can use Gpedit.msc to replace the standard explorer shell with "chrome.exe -kiosk http:///"

Replace  with the acual address you want displayed and omit the "s...